# Malayalam language in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a pdf  in Malayalam language using tkinter and reportlab. The operating system in Manjaro. I am able to use malayalam in LibreOffice , text documents etc. But When I run the following code It do not appear properly in TKinter. In pdf I get black coloured squares only. " ഗോപന്‍ ഇവിടെ വരിക ഈ പക്ഷിയെ കാണുക"  is the text I am trying to type.

```
from tkinter import *
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
#-*-coding :utf_8 -*-
import unicodedata

akhilGui = Tk()
akhilGui.title("Malayalam")

def func_makepdf():
    
  
    v1= u'ഗോപന്‍ ഇവിടെ വരിക ഈ പക്ഷിയെ കാണുക' #This is the malayalam content which i Want to print as pdf
    v2= v1.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
    c = canvas.Canvas("Malayalam-test.pdf")
    c.drawString(50,800,str(v2))
    resLabel = Label(text= str(v2), fg="#113B53",
           font = "meera", justify='center')
    resLabel.grid(row=2, column=1)

  
    c.save()
    

button_pdf= Button(text="PRINT", fg="#113B53",
           font = "Helvetica 16 bold",command=func_makepdf, justify='center')
button_pdf.grid(row=0,column=0, pady=20, padx=15, sticky= EW)

akhilGui.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the resulting PDF file. Also, when you convert the .txt file  with Malayalam text into a PDF, does the PDF display the text correctly?

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you are using python3? Your code looks like you are trying to make this run in python2.

Comment: @DapperDuck Let me verify. I Shall include the Screen shot

Comment: @Novel I want to run it in both 3 and 2 by just changing tkinter to Tkinter.

Comment: Python2 is very bad at unicode. Also it's unmaintained and more than 10 years out of date. I recommend you use python3 only.

Comment: @Novel At present I am using a system with python 3 and still not working

Comment: @GopakumarPB Is this the pdf that results from running the program?

Comment: @DapperDuck Yes! It shows nothing Except the black squares. As you suggested I verified whether .txt files converted as pdf are fine. Yes!

Comment: I ran the program and it works fine for me

Comment: @GopakumarPB Try updating the reportlab and unicodedata modules with ```pip install --upgrade <module name>```

Comment: @DapperDuck could you please upload the screen shot?

Comment: @GopakumarPB Ok, one second. I will update this comment with a link.

Comment: @GopakumarPB Here is the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/oGOHJOk)

Comment: @GopakumarPB I too get black squares with my pdf as seen [here](https://imgur.com/a/4KraZqR)

Comment: I believe the problem might be because of ReportLab. Read part 3.3 of the [documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), which I believe is the solution to the problem.

Comment: You need to register the "meera" font and use it in the output PDF. See [Developer FAQ](https://www.reportlab.com/documentation/faq/#2.6.2).

Comment: [screenshott](https://imgur.com/IkSB86g) using "meera" font.